# Change line chart area color in Angular-NVD3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-nvd3

I'm using the Angular-NVD3 library to show some line charts, I've seen that I can set an "area" property to 'true' in the data so that the area of the graph will be colored.

```
{
    values: [/** some data **/],
    key: 'Cosine Wave',
    color: '#2ca02c',
    area: true
}
```

[live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lXV7rNpNGBpYWeDh7JPI?p=preview)

but I cannot find how to change the color of the area. by default the chart colors the area to a lighter hue of the line color, but I need it as a light gray.

Does the API ($scope.options) even allow for such an option? is there a way to 'hack' it ?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?!?!

Comment: well.. technically d3 is svg and svg is a part of the DOM, I've tried using css to select the area and maybe somehow manipulate it, but couldn't get it right, but it is possible. I think it's a prime candidate for a feature request.

Comment: @iggymoran check out the posted solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened an [issue in github](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/302) and got a response from the author, he advised changing the area's css rules and provided this snippet

```
.nvd3 .nv-group.nv-series-0 {
     fill: lightgray!important; /* color for area */
}
```

(`0` being the line index).

I tested it in a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gDI27r?p=preview) and it works as needed!